# How to make snapshot and roll back to later with Microsoft Edge test Virtual Machines?

Tags: internet-explorer, virtualbox, rollback, microsoft-edge

[So Microsoft provides us with free VMs with different IE/Edge versions for 90 days.](http://dev.modern.ie/tools/vms/windows/) They have a disclaimer that says following:

> Please note that these virtual machines expire after 90 days. We recommend setting a snapshot when you first install the virtual machine which you can roll back to later.

How does one do that? Lets assume I want to use Virtual Box as my VM provider.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here is a guide](http://www.howtogeek.com/150258/how-to-save-time-by-using-snapshots-in-virtualbox/).

Basically just right click on the VM and "take snapshot". You can roll back at any time by shutting down the VM, right click, and select restore.